# Grouped By, Weighted, Column Averages in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have two value columns and two weight columns in a Pandas DataFrame, and I want to generate a third column that is the grouped by, weighted, average of those two columns.

So for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category':['a','a','b','b'],
  'var1':np.random.randint(0,100,4),
  'var2':np.random.randint(0,100,4),
  'weights1':np.random.random(4),
  'weights2':np.random.random(4)})
df
  category  var1  var2  weights1  weights2
0        a    84    45  0.955234  0.729862
1        a    49     5  0.225470  0.159662
2        b    77    95  0.957212  0.991960
3        b    27    65  0.491877  0.195680
```

I'd want to accomplish:

```
df
  category  var1  var2  weights1  weights2    average
0        a    84    45  0.955234  0.729862  67.108023
1        a    49     5  0.225470  0.159662  30.759124
2        b    77    95  0.957212  0.991960  86.160443
3        b    27    65  0.491877  0.195680  37.814851
```

I've already accomplished this using just arithmetic operators like this:

```
df['average'] = df.groupby('category', group_keys=False) \
  .apply(lambda g: (g.weights1 * g.var1 + g.weights2 * g.var2) / (g.weights1 + g.weights2))
```

But I want to generalize it to using numpy.average, so I could for example take the weighted average of 3 columns or more.

I'm trying something like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
df['average'] = df.groupby('category', group_keys=False) \
  .apply(lambda g: np.average([g.var1, g.var2], axis=0, weights=[g.weights1, g.weights2]))
```

returning

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: How excatly do you want this new column to line up with the original dataframe? Since there is less values in the group by than the original dataframe pandas doesn't know how to line up the new column with the original dataframe. Can you post a sample of the dataframe and expected output

Comment: The number of values should be the same, since it's just taking a weighted average over columns that already exist in each group. I'll add a sample dataframe and output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't even think you need `groupby` here. Notice, this matches the output with `apply` + `lambda`.

Try this:

```
col=df.drop('category',1)
s=col.groupby(col.columns.str.findall(r'\d+').str[0],axis=1).prod().sum(1)
s/df.filter(like='weight').sum(1)
Out[33]: 
0    67.108014
1    30.759168
2    86.160444
3    37.814871
dtype: float64
```

Comment: +1 for  using like in this case. I filtered on non weighted columns but I did not realize that was an option.

Comment: If you are just using the last charachter of the weights and var columns to determine which to multiply, then this will only work for up to 9 var and weight columns

Answer (score 0):

Since you have one value in average column for every row in the df, you don't really need to groupby. You just need a dynamic way of computing the average for a variable number of `'varXXX'` columns.

The answer below relies on the same number of 'var' columns and 'weights' columns, with a consistent naming pattern, as it constructs the column name string

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                   'var1': np.random.randint(0, 100, 4),
                   'var2': np.random.randint(0, 100, 4),
                   'var3': np.random.randint(0, 100, 4),
                   'weights1': np.random.random(4),
                   'weights2': np.random.random(4),
                   'weights3': np.random.random(4)
                   })

n_cols = len([1 for i in df.columns if i[:3] == 'var'])

def weighted_av_func(x):
    numerator = 0
    denominator = 0
    for i in range(1, n_cols + 1):
        numerator += x['var{}'.format(i)] * x['weights{}'.format(i)]
        denominator += x['weights{}'.format(i)]
    return numerator / denominator

df['average'] = df.apply(weighted_av_func, axis=1)

print(df)

  category  var1  var2  var3  weights1  weights2  weights3    average
0        a    53    58     2  0.101798  0.073881  0.919632  10.517238
1        a    52     0    26  0.073988  0.816425  0.888792  15.150578
2        b    30    78    46  0.641875  0.029402  0.370237  37.042735
3        b    36    72    92  0.186941  0.663270  0.774427  77.391136
```

Edit:
If you want to use np.average, and can guarantee the ordering of var columns and weights columns in your dataframe, then you could do this:

```
df['np_average'] = df.apply(
lambda x: np.average(a=x[1:1 + n_cols], 
                     weights=x[n_cols + 1:2 * n_cols + 1]), 
                     axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                   'var1': np.random.randint(0, 100, 4),
                   'var2': np.random.randint(0, 100, 4),
                   'weights1': np.random.random(4),
                   'weights2': np.random.random(4)})

df_averages = df[df.columns.difference(['category', 'var1', 'var2'])]
```

Output:

```
    weights1    weights2
0   0.002812    0.483088
1   0.159774    0.818346
2   0.285366    0.586706
3   0.427240    0.428667

df_averages['Average'] = df_averages.mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    weights1    weights2    Average
0   0.002812    0.483088    0.242950
1   0.159774    0.818346    0.489060
2   0.285366    0.586706    0.436036
3   0.427240    0.428667    0.427954

df['Averages'] = df_averages['Average'].astype(float)
```

Output:

```
  category  var1    var2    weights1    weights2    Averages
0   a        60      22     0.002812    0.483088    0.242950
1   a        66      63     0.159774    0.818346    0.489060
2   b        18      10     0.285366    0.586706    0.436036
3   b        68      32     0.427240    0.428667    0.427954
```

Essentially remove the non weighted columns from the dataframe and move the weighted columns to a new one. Then you can apply the mean across the rows of that dataframe and merge it back in since the index will till be the same.